# Type mismatch in key from map In Hadoop Sorting

Tags: java, hadoop

I am creating a simple hadoop sorting example, I have following code.

I am using ready-made  InverseMaper and Identity reducer

```
        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[1]));

        conf.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);

        conf.setOutputKeyClass(LongWritable.class);
        conf.setOutputValueClass(LongWritable.class);

        conf.setMapOutputKeyClass(LongWritable.class);
        conf.setMapOutputValueClass(LongWritable.class);

        conf.setMapperClass(InverseMapper.class);
        conf.setReducerClass(IdentityReducer.class);

        conf.setNumReduceTasks(1);
```

This is my input file data -

```
432
532
5234
43
65
524
15
56
96
25
3251
369845
58
249
354
```

When I run this code, I am getting following error. Could anyone help?

```
15/10/28 15:25:09 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: map task executor complete.
15/10/28 15:25:09 WARN mapred.LocalJobRunner: job_local2001686703_0001
java.lang.Exception: java.io.IOException: Type mismatch in key from map: expected org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable, received org.apache.hadoop.io.Text
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:462)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:522)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Type mismatch in key from map: expected org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable, received org.apache.hadoop.io.Text
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.collect(MapTask.java:1069)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$OldOutputCollector.collect(MapTask.java:607)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.InverseMapper.map(InverseMapper.java:42)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:450)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:243)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that **TextInputFormat extends FileInputFormat<\LongWritable,Text>** so the mapper is not reading in the right format.

From documentation:

> An InputFormat for plain text files. Files are broken into lines. Either linefeed or carriage-return are used to signal end of line. Keys are the position in the file, and **values are the line of text**.